# Tosca: Can we scan Notepad.exe?

Tags: tosca

So, as I'm learning Tosca, I tried to scan the simple program Notepad.exe that comes with windows...  and I can't seem to figure it out.  Is it even possible with Tosca 9.2?  Is it possible with Tosca 10?

The best I was able to do so far was to scan Notepad as an "other", and switch on the Options > Use UIAEngine...  and then it was only really able to see the main editbox... menu headers could be scanned, but none of the menu options like file > Open...  or Edit > Replace...  which would make being able to automate Notepad.exe useful.

Is it just not possible yet?

Comment: Use tbox start program module under standard module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with TOSCA 10. I just tried and scanned Notepad instance with Desktop option from `Module Folder > [right click] Scan Application > Desktop`. It shows all the open browsers, Notepad instance, folders and desktop.

I scanned a module of Notepad which had only two attributes (because I selected only those) - Text area of Notepad and its close button. I created a test case where I inputted 'This' in the text area and clicked the close button. The test case also works fine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The performance is much faster if you use the below modules instead of opening it UI. You can read/write and play around in the text file.

1. TBox Read/Create File
2. File system operations
3. TEXTSTREAM